# AttributeError: 'OWM' object has no attribute 'weather_at_coords'

Tags: python, python-3.x, openweathermap

The [PyOWM 3 documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyowm/latest/pyowm.pdf#page=24) states to find the weather at a coordinate using `weather_at_coords(lat, lon)`. I'm trying to find the weather of a coordinate, however I keep getting `AttributeError: 'OWM' object has no attribute 'weather_at_coords'`. I have PyOWM 3.1.1 and I'm using Python 3.9.

Here's my code. Essentially the same as the example in the documentation:

```
from python.owm import OWM
owm = OWM('API KEY')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
lat = 0
lon = 0
current_weather = owm.weather_at_coords(lat, lon).weather
print(current_weather)
```

What is causing this error? Do I have the wrong version of PyOWM?

Comment: You want `mgr.weather_at_coords`, not `owm.weather_at_coords`.

Comment: @larsks Thanks. That seems to be the issue. Very strange that the official documentation got it wrong.

Comment: It looks like it has been fixed in the sources in [#daaf4100](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/commit/daaf4100). I guess the PDF docs haven't been regenerated since then.

Comment: Oh. So it's a fairly recent change?

Comment: I guess? You now know everything I know on this topic :).